# Weird behavior of jquery's if condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker plugin, here is the code:
http://dpaste.com/639849/

The real problem lies in hightlight function in which the if condition never gets executed. The if condition in question is:

```
if ($('#id_checkin').datepicker('getDate') == date) {
  return [false, ''];
 }
```

Although i have tried outputting the values of both date variable and $('#id_checkin').datepicker('getDate') using console.log. At one point, both values are exactly the same. Here is the output of both values:

Fri Oct 28 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530
Fri Oct 28 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0530

My problem is, if they match in value, why does not if statement believe so ? :(
Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Try printing the date object's milliseconds value. They are probably different (and milliseconds is not being output in console) which would cause the equality operation to fail

Comment: Just because they print the same doesn't mean they'll be `==`. Convert one or the other to a string if you want to compare `string`ily, or do a proper date comparison appropriate to what you want.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but what is the appropriate way to compare two dates?

Answer (score 1):

Are they of the same type or simply stringify to the same representation? Try change that to `if ($('#id_checkin').datepicker('getDate').toString() == date.toString())` and see what happens.

edit: as to why... It could be because one of those values is some weird date object. JavaScript will try to coerce the types, but it will likely only work on types it knows about. My second guess is that one (or both) of those dates have a non-zero millisecond portion. Since milliseconds are not included in the output produced by called `toString()`, it is possible they match on their string representation but not on actual value. Try to output `value` property (assuming both sides are valid Date object) and see whats going on there.

Comment: This isn't going to make a difference.  Javascript will coerce the two to the same type.

Comment: Wow, this worked, thanks a lot. But i am just wondering that how can getDate function and date parameter can be of different representation? Anyways thanks a lot, i was splitting my hair on this.

Comment: I don't know. Try looking at `jQuery.type()` of the expressions on each side. Likely one is a date and another one is a string.